# Hi,I want to delete a node in the linked list, but i can't, i've thought for a whole day and in my opion, it can work well

Tags: c

there will be a segment error in the middle of the run, here is my code

```
Pstu DeleteNode(char * name)                                                                       │
{                                                                                                  │
    Pstu Pn = Phead;                                                                               │
    Pstu Pm = Pn;                                                                                  │
    int flag = 1;                                                                                  │
                                                                                                   │
    if(Pn == Pend)                                                                                 │
    {                                                                                              │
                                                                                                   │
        if(Pn == NULL)                                                                             │
        {                                                                                          │
            printf("you need to add some student first!");                                         │
            return NULL;                                                                           │
        }                                                                                          │
        else if(!strcmp(Pn->name,Pn->name))                                                        │
        {                                                                                          │
            printf("only1 and get it!");                                                           │
                                                                                                   │
            return Pn;                                                                             │
        }                                                                                          │
    }                                                                                              │
    else if(Pn->next == Pend)                                                                      │
                    free(Pn);                                                                      │
    else                                                                                           │
    {                                                                                              │
        while(Pn != Pend )                                                                         │
        {                                                                                          │
            if(!strcmp(Pn->name,name))                                                             │
            {                                                                                      │
                    if(flag == 1)                                                                  │
                    {           free(Pn);                                                          │
                        break;                                                                     │
                    }                                                                              │
                    else                                                                           │
                    {                                                                              │
                        free(Pn);                                                                  │
                        Pn = Pn->next;                                                             │
                        Pm->next = Pn;                                                             │
                        printf("infindwhile get it");                                              │
                        return Pm;                                                                 │
                    }                                                                              │
                                                                                                   │
            }                                                                                      │
            else  if(flag == 0)    
{                                                                                      │
                Pm = Pn;                                                                           │
                Pn = Pn->next;                                                                     │
                Pm->next = Pn;                                                                     │
            }                                                                                      │
            else                                                                                   │
            {                                                                                      │
                flag = 0;                                                                          │
                Pn = Pn->next;                                                                     │
                                                                                                   │
                Pm->next = Pn;                                                                     │
            }                                                                                      │
        }                                                                                          │
        if(!strcmp(Pn->name,name))                                                                 │
        {                                                                                          │
                free(Pn);                                                                          │
                printf("finally delete it");                                                       │
                printf("%d\n",Pn->score);                                                          │
                return Pm;                                                                         │
        }                                                                                          │
        else                                                                                       │
            printf("no one\n");                                                                    │
    }
```

Comment: hi guys, the code may be to long, before this function , there are the two struct nodes :Phead,Pend;       The struct contains 3:the name , age and a pointer to a struct of this kind.    the linked list has already been buit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appart from the fact that your implementation seems WAY TOO BIG for just a node delete function (should take around 10 lines), here are a few advices you should care about :

- You should never EVER use memory after having free'd it like you did here

```
else
{
    free(Pn);
    Pn = Pn->next;
    Pm->next = Pn;
    printf("infindwhile get it");
    return Pm;
}
```

- Always check all code paths for a return value. In certain cases, your function does not return anything.
- Be clearer when naming variables. (between Pm and Pn, i don't really know what you mean, and sometimes, it feels like even you don't know anymore)
- Precise what you want as a return value for your function, because even the return value isn't clear depending on which part of the function we check.